# How to reply image in line-bot-sdk v3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am maintaining a weather linebot, while I encountered some issues related to replying images in the new version of line-bot-sdk python. Below are codes for replying images.

Codes for generating image message

```
with ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
        body = request.get_json()
        line_bot_api = MessagingApi(api_client)
        today_image_content = ImageMessageContent(
                    id=body["events"][0]["message"]["id"],
                    contentProvider=ContentProvider(
                        type="external",
                        originalContentUrl=today_image_link,
                        previewImageUrl=today_image_link
                    ),
                    quoteToken=body["events"][0]["message"] 
 ["quoteToken"]
        )
```

Codes for sending that message

```
line_bot_api.reply_message_with_http_info(
                ReplyMessageRequest(
                    reply_token=event.reply_token,
                    messages=[today_image_content]
                )
            )
```

Error Messages

```
Error: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Server': 'legy', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-frame-options': 'DENY', 'x-line-request-id': 'd484f011-ca9f-4639-ab4d-a9dfe64a6c22', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'Content-Length': '204', 'Expires': 'Sat, 10 Feb 2024 05:08:01 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Sat, 10 Feb 2024 05:08:01 GMT', 'Connection': 'close'})
HTTP response body: {"message":"The request body has 2 error(s)","details":[{"message":"May not be empty","property":"messages[0].originalContentUrl"},{"message":"May not be empty","property":"messages[0].previewImageUrl"}]}
```

While I am pretty sure that `today_image_link` is not empty, and the URL is also valid.
`print(today_image_link) #https://i.imgur.com/adrlVWT.png`

What could be the problems?